# split Tel and Fax numbers from this string using regex

Tags: regex

**Consider the below given is a string**

PO BOX number 1234,
CA - 3265
TEL: +1-200-200-2000 FAX: +1-200-200-2001 
PO BOX number 1234,
CA - 3265 Service: +1-200-200-2002 \ +1-200-200-2022 F : +1-200-200-2003 
PO BOX number 1234,
CA - 3265 care: +1-200-200-2004 f : +1-200-200-2005 
PO BOX number 1234,
CA - 3265 fire: +1-200-200-2006 fax : +1-200-200-2007 
PO BOX number 1234,
CA - 3265 help: +1-200-200-2008 fax - +1-200-200-2009 
PO BOX number 1234,
CA - 3265 fax : (+123)-4567890 \ (+123)-4567891

The regular expression mentioned below is the one I'm using for finding a fax number in different representation

```
(?:(f|F)((a|A)(X|x))?(?:\s?(\-|\:)?\s?))(?:\s?[0-9\+\.\(\)\/\\\-]\/?\\?\s?){7,30}
```

**Ex: The above regex would match all the Fax from the given string as shown below**

FAX: +1-200-200-2001 
F : +1-200-200-2003 
f : +1-200-200-2005 
fax : +1-200-200-2007 
fax - +1-200-200-2009 
fax : (+123)-4567890 \ (+123)-4567891

**Note:** I am considering the phone numbers as rest of the numbers available in the given text apart from taking the FAX. 
**Ex:**
TEL: +1-200-200-2000 
Service: +1-200-200-2002 \ +1-200-200-2022 
care: +1-200-200-2004 
fire: +1-200-200-2006 
help: +1-200-200-2008

**So I need the phone numbers whose text not starts with [faxFAX]**. I have tried with `[^faxFAX]` just changing the above specified regular expression but I couldn't get the desired result.please help me out to write a regular expression for this.

Comment: I can use this
`[bcdeghijklmnopqrstuvwyzBCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ]+` 
but it'll neglect if the text before the number ends with **f|a|x|F|A|X**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
(?:(f|F)((a|A)(X|x))?(?:\s?(\-|\:)?\s?))(?:\s?[0-9\+\.\(\)\/\\\-]\/?\\?\s?){7,30}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:\s?[0-9\+\.\(\)\/\\\-]\/?\\?\s?){7,30}
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bU6nB9/1)

**Edit:** [`Explanation of (*SKIP)(*FAIL}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) as suggested in the comments.

Comment: [Explanation of SKIP and FAIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex). A brief summary in the answer itself would also be good.

Comment: @karthikmanchala hi I have some problem with the regex you gave, when I utilized that and tried in [http://www.regexr.com]
and of course it gives me the same, when I was using the same regex in my code.

Comment: @VinodhVelumayil `regexr` uses javascript regex engine.. and (*SKIP) (*FAIL) are not supported in javascript.. but in PCRE, PHP.. are you using javascript?.

Comment: @karthikmanchala yes exactly I have told you that I am using the language **R** so it gets me the same output like try that regex with removing (star) from SKIP and FAIL

Comment: @VinodhVelumayil `(*SKIP) (*FAIL)` works in R.. are you sure it is not because of other issues?

Comment: @karthikmanchala yep I have verified it. It doesn't works well, as it is taking the fax along with the expected result.